# wiimote installation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody
I read on the ros.org wiki site (http://ros.org/wiki/wiimote#The_State_Message) about the wiimote, but on item number 4 which states "Check out the wiimote package, and rosmake to ready the package for operation. Plug the Bluetooth dongle into your machine's USB port.", what does it mean "Check out the wiimote package"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45119/wiimote-installation/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the wiki site is sort of outdated. I would not suggest to build the package from source since there are debian packages available. To install the stack `joystick_drivers` in fuerte, enter the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means you download the code from the development server. With rosmake you compile the code on your system.
You can type in the commandline:

- svn co https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/joystick_drivers/trunk/wiimote
- cd wiimote
- rosmake

This not really clearly explained in the tutorials I think.

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) on 2013-03-15**:
It is not, you may update the wiki page, but anyway it is assumed some previous knowledge about using 3rd party packages, from the tutorials. Maybe the wiki of most 3rd p software should be changed.